# When to pay IT in India on income in Japan under DTAA?

Tags: taxes, india, payment, dtaa, japan

I am staying in Japan and have signed for paying IT in India under DTAA.

My company will give me statement of income while I return to India after full stay period, i.e., two years.

Do I pay tax in India on the whole income only after getting the statement, i.e., for two years at one go after returning to India?